# Golang struct having io.Reader unable to serialize

Tags: serialization, go, deserialization

I am trying to serialize below struct into `byte[]` to store it into DB and then while reading it from DB I am deserializing it.

```
type Response struct {
    Headers map[string][]string
    Body    io.Reader
    Status  int
}
```

Below is the code how I am creating response object and setting up the value for it.

```
resp := new(Response)
resp.Body = bytes.NewReader(outBytes) //outBytes is byte[]
resp.Headers.SetKeyValue("Content-Type", "text/json") //SetKeyValue is the method created for adding headers
resp.Headers.SetKeyValue("Url-Type", "broker")
resp.Status = 200
```

I am using `json.Marshal()` to serialize the `resp` object as below.

```
b, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
```

Below is the code, I am using to deserialize.

```
var r Response
r.Body = &bytes.Buffer{}
json.Unmarshal(b,&r)
```

Problem is with deserialization, I am not able to get the `resp.Body` object. It is always `nil` or blank in spite of setting body object (see above). I am able to get `Headers` and `Status` field of the struct back from deserialize but not `Body`.

I know there is something to be handle with `Body` field which is an `io.Reader`.

Any help would be really great.

Comment: You're using the wrong structure, `io.Reader` is just and interface and `bytes.Reader` doesn't have any exported attributes, for that reason `Body` is blank. You should change the type of `Body` to something helpful to you, like `string`, or you can use just `[]byte`

Comment: Thanks, I have defined Body field to to a stream which can read data from any stream, I can't change the field type.

Comment: I didn't get why someone devoted my question.

Comment: if `Headers` is a map  how is there a function 'SetKeyValue` on it ?

Comment: I have defined a type type Headers map[HeaderKey][]string and Headers is of type Headers and then that method is of this type. Just to make my question small, I have put the short version of it.
You can think that method is just a method to add Headers.

Comment: @praveen.upadhyay check my answer this is the right way to do this in `golang`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer :** JSON marshaller will not use `Read()` function to read the  string from io.Reader . Instead of using `io.Reader` you may use a type that implements `Marshaler` interface.

**How Marshaller works :** 
Marshal traverses the value v recursively. If an encountered value implements the `Marshaler` interface and is not a nil pointer, Marshal calls its `MarshalJSON` method to produce JSON. If no MarshalJSON method is present but the value implements `encoding.TextMarshaler` instead, Marshal calls its `MarshalText` method. The nil pointer exception is not strictly necessary but mimics a similar, necessary exception in the behavior of UnmarshalJSON.

Otherwise, Marshal uses the following `type-dependent` default encodings:

- Boolean values encode as JSON booleans.
- Floating point, integer, and Number values encode as JSON numbers.

**Implementaton**
This is what you may do

```
type Response struct {
    Headers map[string][]string
    Body    *JSONReader
    Status  int
}

type JSONReader struct {
    *bytes.Reader
}

func NewJSONReader(outBytes []byte) *JSONReader {
    jr := new(JSONReader)
    jr.Reader = bytes.NewReader(outBytes)
    return jr
}

func (js JSONReader) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(js.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    data = []byte(`"` + string(data) + `"`)
    return data, nil
}

// UnmarshalJSON sets *jr to a copy of data.
func (jr *JSONReader) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if jr == nil {
        return errors.New("json.JSONReader: UnmarshalJSON on nil pointer")
    }
    if data == nil {
        return nil
    }
    data = []byte(strings.Trim(string(data), "\""))
    jr.Reader = bytes.NewReader(data)
    return nil
}
```

Here is a go playground link with the implementation and sample use : [link](https://play.golang.org/p/O8OexgunfX)

Comment: You may have to implement `UnmarshalJSON` for the same type for unmarshalling the json to the reader

Comment: Added UnmarshalJSON also. You may use it directly in your code now

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am only worried about this solution is that, the Response object will tightly be coupled with JSON serialization. What I want to do is to have the Response object generic and based on the Content-Type header, serialization and deserialization can be used, so that it can be flexible enough to even deal with XML serialization. Can't we use the Response struct as it is in my question ?

Comment: All you need to make that work is you need to implement `UnmarshalXML` and `MarshalXML` functions aswell to the struct you created and probaly name it properly to be explicit  :D . This is the best you can do

Comment: @praveen.upadhyay you may not use the response struct as you have it in your question as     `Body    io.Reader` does not implement Marshaller or Unmarshaller and the golang json decoder defaults to encode the `exported fields` inside the object `*bytes.Reader` . `*bytes.Reader` does not have any exported fileds

https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader

Comment: Yas I get that. Thanks. I will accept your solution as answer after few hours (as I need to rethink some other way around).

Comment: @praveen.upadhyay that is fine. I believe this should be the most `go`ish way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

#### Overview

[`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) is an interface so it can't be marshaled. Each marshaling struct attribute must implement [`Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface to be marshaled. You could declare your own marshaler wrapper struct to marshal data from `bytes.Reader`.

#### Why interface can't be marshaled?

Interfaces in Go provide a way to specify the behavior of an object: if something can do this, then it can be used here. In opposite Go’s structs are typed collections of fields. They’re useful for grouping data together to form records. Go supports methods defined on struct types not interface types.

#### Implementation

```
type Response struct {
    Body *MarshalableReader
}

type MarshalableReader struct {
    *bytes.Reader
}

func (r MarshalableReader) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", data)), nil
}

func main() {
    resp := Response{&MarshalableReader{bytes.NewReader([]byte("Blah Blah"))}}

    marshaled, err := json.Marshal(resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("JSON: %s\n", marshaled)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `"encoding/json"` package : https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

As I can use the http.ResponseWriter to send JSON Response. Here is two functions you could use to send JSON and read JSON from the body :

```
// GetJSONContent returns the JSON content of a request
func GetJSONContent(v interface{}, r *http.Request) error {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(v)
}

// JSONWithHTTPCode Json Output with an HTTP code
func JSONWithHTTPCode(w http.ResponseWriter, d interface{}, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    if d != nil {
        err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(d)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your handlers just use those func as follow :

```
// Handler handler
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        s := YourStruct{}
        err = GetJSONContent(s, r) 
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        return
    }

    JSONWithHTTPCode(w, s, http.StatusOK)
}
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Not helpful. I am not dealing with http response.

Comment: You could use the package without http response, please read the link of the package I've gived to you ...

Comment: Thanks, but I have looked at it and not able to solve my problem.

Comment: [Encoding](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.Encode)
[Decoding](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode)

Comment: I did try this also but not helping. Problem is with the io.Reader type.